# using window.speechSynthesis is it possible to change pronunciation?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I've got a text-to-speech website using the built-in window.speechSynthesis and it works pretty well.  But I want to know if it's possible to alter the pronunciation of a word when the computer reads it wrong.  This usually happens in proper names.  I specifically want to alter the ***stress***  of a word.  I was thinking I could pass in the word spelled phonetically somehow to force the voice to read it that way.

For an example: the computer reads the street name Glassell like "**GLA**sl" (accent on the first syllable) when I want it to be pronounced "gla**SEL**" accent on second syllable.

Is this possible?

Comment: I may be wrong, but IIRC, no browser supports [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) and the [`<phoneme>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.1.10) tag, so currently we can't speak IPA with built-in TTS. However, [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/is-there-an-online-tool-to-convert-ipa-symbols-into-audio-sound)  claims that Amazon's Polly does support it, maybe an option for you?